# Importing strings from a file, into a list, using python

Tags: python, list

I have a txt file, with these contents:

```
a,b
c,d
e,f
g,h
i,j
k,l
```

And i am putting them into a list, using these lines:

```
keywords=[]
solutions=[]
for i in file:
    keywords.append((i.split(","))[0])
    solutions.append(((i.split(","))[1]))
```

but when I print() the solutions, here is what it displays:

```
['b\n', 'd\n', 'f\n', 'h\n', 'j\n', 'l']
```

How do I make it, so that the \n-s are removed from the ends of the first 5 elements, bu the last element is left unaltered, using as few lines as possible.

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to call `i.split` twice; `a, b = i.split(","); keywords.append(a); solutions.append(b)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [`string.strip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.strip) the whitespace/new-line characters from the string after reading it to remove the `\n`:

```
keywords=[]
solutions=[]
for i_raw in file:
    i = i_raw.strip() # <-- removes extraneous spaces from start/end of string 
    keywords.append((i.split(","))[0])
    solutions.append(((i.split(","))[1]))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `str.strip()` in order to trimming the last whitespace. But as a more pythonic approach you better to use `csv` module for loading your file content which will accept a delimiter and return an iterable contain tuples of separated items (here, the characters). The use `zip()` function to get the columns.

```
import csv
with open(file_name) as f:
    reader_obj = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',') # here passing the delimiter is optional because by default it will consider comma as delimiter.
    first_column, second_column = zip(*reader_obj)
```